# Need to extract a value from XML response in Jmeter with the help of XPath Extractor

Tags: xml, xpath, jmeter

In JMeter, I am trying to extract value from my XML response which I can reuse in the upcoming request, but I want to extract this value with the help of XPath Extractor. Below is the XML response:

```
<GwtResponse>
  <object class="com.sandbox.bluesky.platform.gwt.common.FoldersStringResult">
<__folders>&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;yes&quot;?&gt;&lt;Folders&gt;&lt;Folder id=&quot;935&quot; parentId=&quot;-1&quot; name=&quot;ApnpdQA_TestAccount&quot; type=&quot;folder&quot; deleted=&quot;false&quot; writeRestriction=&quot;NONE&quot;&gt;&lt;Category name=&quot;Map Functions&quot; singular=&quot;Map Function&quot; id=&quot;935&quot; parentId=&quot;-1&quot; type=&quot;transform.function&quot; className=&quot;MapFunction&quot; resource=&quot;mapfunction16&quot;&gt;&lt;Component name=&quot;Abhiram Test MapFunction_1572016185208&quot; id=&quot;000c7cc9-84ce-4546-9198-4860c8567c4c&quot; version=&quot;1&quot; type=&quot;transform.function&quot; dirty=&quot;false&quot; dirtySincePublished=&quot;false&quot; deleted=&quot;</__folders>
  </object>
</GwtResponse>
```

From this response, I am looking to extract the "ApnpdQA_TestAccount" value and parameterize it to use in the following requests. I am still new to XPath Extractor Post Processor so any help will be useful

Answer (score 0):

Given your XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Folders>
    <Folder id="935" parentId="-1" name="ApnpdQA_TestAccount" type="folder" deleted=""></Folder>
</Folders>
```

1. To get `name` attribute from the folder it's quite enough to use the following XPath expression:

   ```
   //Folder/@name
   ```

   [image]
2. To get `name` attribute of the folder with `id` of `935` - use the following query:

   ```
   //Folder[@id='935']/@name
   ```

   [image]
3. If above expressions are not helpful consider adding full XML response to your question

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XSLT/XPath Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath)
- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0/)

Comment: I have uploaded a full XML response in my question, please take a look at it as I tried the above suggestions and it didn't return any value. Thank you so much for your help